# maximum in a month, sum of amount to find max per month

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have following data and I am trying to find the transaction with maximum value against each month and then take the sum of the maximum value in each month against each customer and display the final result.

```
1,2008-04-10,111,300
2,2008-04-09,112,400
3,2008-04-04,111,950
4,2008-05-01,113,900
5,2008-05-05,113,1100
6,2009-05-03,112,1200
7,2009-07-02,111,1700
8,2009-07-09,111,2000
9,2009-07-03,112,1250
10,2009-07-01,112,1150
```

My query is

```
select 
     o.Date, max(o.amount) from sample o 
join 
     player c on o.player = c.player 
group by o.player;
```

the result should be like this

```
2008-04-04    950
2008-05-03    1200
2009-07-09    2000
```

and

```
111     1250
113     2000
```

Can I temporarily store the result of the first query to get the result for second query?

Comment: break your query and try the answer below for multiple

Comment: How did you get the last output? Can you please elaborate on that?